# How to use the same variable in two different jQuery events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a rating system and want to pull up each rating value by the jquery.
For this purpose I am doing like this, but I am unable to get previous event variable value into next event.

```
var r1Rating;
    $(".rating-input").on("click",function(){
        //alert($(this).attr("id"));

        var r1=$(this).attr("id");
        var r1Array=r1.split("-");
        //alert(r1Array[r1Array.length-1]);
        var r1Rating=parseInt(r1Array[r1Array.length-1]).toFixed(2);
        $("#total_rating").html(r1Rating);
        var r1Rating=r1Rating;
    });

$(".rating-input1").on("click",function(){
        alert(r1Rating); //I want to get value here
});
```

Any help, suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you are creating `r1Rating` again in your function. remove the `var`

Comment: Do `r1Rating=parseInt(r1Array[r1Array.length-1]).toFixed(2);` (without the `var`), and remove the last line of your first function (`var r1rating = ..`)

Comment: don't declare new variable `r1Rating` inside the first click event listener (remove var keyword), and you will be able to use the one defined in the outer scope (first line)

Comment: See regarding variable's scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript  That's said, if you provide relevant HTML markup, it should be better way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you have a r1Rating in the external scope, since you are using `var r1Rating` in the click handler, you are creating a new locally scoped variable in the click handler. So any changes you make to the variable will be visible inside that method only and the variable in the external scope will not be updated.

```
var r1Rating;
$(".rating-input").on("click", function () {
    //alert($(this).attr("id"));

    var r1 = $(this).attr("id");
    var r1Array = r1.split("-");

    //should not use var here
    r1Rating = parseInt(r1Array[r1Array.length - 1]).toFixed(2);
    $("#total_rating").html(r1Rating);
});

$(".rating-input1").on("click", function () {
    alert(r1Rating); //I want to get value here
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The code below should be changes, since in this instance, you created a new r1Rating variable in a scope, which means that this was a different variable from the global one outside.

```
var r1Rating=r1Rating;
```

This should be changed to:

```
r1Rating=r1Rating;
```

Comment: OP is declaring `r1Rating` twice. I know, doesn't really make sense

Comment: this answer does not make sense too

Comment: @Hacketo It would make sense if OP wasn't declaring same variable twice. EDIT: in fact, he's declaring it three times

Comment: @A.Wolff assigning a variable to itself ? It make sense for you ?